# Completion of a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I wonder if there exists an example of vector space $V$ and linearly independent set $U\subset V$ such that $U$ cannot be completed to a basis of $V$.

I feel like $V=\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $U=\{1\}$ might work (apparently there are a lot of linear combinations that give $1$), but I am not sure.

Comment: Ask Zorn; he night know

Comment: What makes you think that {1} cannot be completed to a basis for $r

Comment: No, any  independent set can be extended to a basis.

Comment: It is a standard fact that Zorn's lemma implies the following: if $M$ is a module over a division ring, then for any pair of subsets $(I,G)$ of $M$, where $I$ is linearly independent and $G$ is a generating set, there exists a basis $B$ of $M$ such that $I \subseteq B \subseteq G$.